# Add field to Orchard ContentPart and record is not working

Tags: orchardcms

In my module, I have an `EventPart` and `EventPartRecord`. Everything was working fine until I decided to add a new field `Address2` in the part and record. I thought it would be easy and I modified my Record as follow

```
public virtual String Address2 { get; set; }
```

and then part as

```
public String Address2
{
    get { return Record.Address2; }
    set { Record.Address2 = value; }
}
```

Now to add column in table I added the method in Migration class as follows

```
public int UpdateFrom3()
{
   this.SchemaBuilder.AlterTable(typeof(SupportedEmploymentEventPartRecord).Name
            , table => table.AddColumn("Address2", System.Data.DbType.String, c => c.Nullable().Unlimited()));
   return 4;
}
```

I run the application and column was added in the table. Everything looks good so far.

But strange part is that orchard is not including this new field in update and insert query. I can see that part is updating the `Address2` field from the posted data but somehow Orchard query generation mechanism is ignoring this field.

Can someone please help me to figure out what is going wrong.

thanx

Comment: Don't know this is required or it just happened. But I disable and enable the module from admin and now new orchard started including my new field in sql commands.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the cached NHibernate mappings (**App_Data\Sites\YourSiteName\mappings.bin**) and restart your application. That should help.

Comment: @ZafarYousafi You're welcome. Sometimes mappings don't get refreshed automatically, so you need to do that by hand.

Comment: thanks man!!! why i can vote you only one time???, i don't know how much time i was about to lose if i wasn't seeing your post